# cocoapod : pod setup failed with fatal error

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, git-clone

I successfully installed `cocoapod` by using "gem install cocoapods". After that trying to set up pod by using "pod setup", but gives fatal error.

```
sh-3.2# pod setup

Setting up CocoaPods master repo

[!] Pod::Executable clone 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' master
```

Cloning into 'master'...

```
error: transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining while accessing https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

please help me to solve this..

Comment: This can help You :http://www.raywenderlich.com/12139/introduction-to-cocoapods

Comment: Thanks Lithu T.V. but I am not using sudo here.I am using su(super user) & i used "gem install cocoapods" for installing. for setup its giving fatal: HTTP request failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue appears to be just a temporary network issue. Try to verify if you can clone the https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs repo in a folder manually.

Answer (score 1):

1 - first install git (command line tool for mac)

link to download is : http://git-scm.com/download/mac

2 - then open commind line (or terminal) and type 
$ sudo gem install cocoapods     (you need to wait here , be patient)

3 - now you can shoot the command "pod --version" to check the version of the pod you just installed.

4 - Write again on terminal `$ pod search libpusher` (just an example of a library, you can type any library name here instead of 'libpusher' ).

5- let it be complete , it may take some time.

6- then most imp step , create the pod file , (name can be 'podfile') in your project directory and add it to your project in Xcode.

7 - Now Here the secret is : you need to provide the path to this pod file too here , so type command:

```
cd /Rakesh/vidyo_demo/vidyo_phonegap/ios  (eg.)
```

after cd command rest is the path of the pod file directory.

8- and now when you will type 'pod install ' command in terminal. 
and all libraries (which are written in podfile) will get installed on your project path. just then open the project which now has a workspace file. like demo.xcworkspace (open it)

9- here is the format of pod file:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'libPusher', '~> 1.4'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been already [reported to cocoapods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1344).

> Ok, after a few hours lost, it seems if my project path contains
>   single quotes or spaces, things fail. Sigh.